# Setting custom after_sign_up_path_for in Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

Dependent upon the role (e.g., expert vs. novice) a user selects during registration, I want to redirect him/her to an appropriate page.

I tried overriding the method in the `ApplicationController`. Also tried overriding in my custom `RegistrationsController`:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  if current_user.role = 'xxx'
    redirect_to path1
  else
    redirect_to path2
  end
end
```

I also tried:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  if current_user.role = 'xxx'
    redirect_to path1
  else
    redirect_to path2
  end
  return 
end
```

But the app still redirects to the default `root_path`.

Comment: nope, it went to root_path the default set to .

Comment: did you notice that you using = instead of == ?

Comment: @alex is right. I am sure `path1` is the `root_path` so it redirects to that page.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [devise documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers%3aafter_sign_in_path_for) for your reference

Looking at it, I think you'll have to use `resource` (you're using `current_user`):

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     path = (resource.role == "xx") ? path1 : path2
     redirect_to path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how i resolved , override the method in custom controller , updated routes.rb to map it.

```
   devise_for :users , :path=>'accounts',  controllers: { registrations: "registration" }
```

The controller :

```
 class RegistrationController <  Devise::RegistrationsController   
          def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
            if current_user.role = 'xx'
                   new_expert_path
                else
                   new_user_expertrequest
                end
           end
       end
```

Just removed redirect_to since the parent controller calls this method as follows and doing the redirect

```
# POST /resource <Devise:RegistrationsController>
  def create
       xxxx
    if resource_saved
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        xxxx
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        xxx
    else
     xxxx
    end
  end
```